# How do I find the thread that is leaking because it lacks an NSAutoreleasePool?

Tags: objective-c, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I'm getting this message when I run my app:

```
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xadf5e50 of class __NSDate autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

I understand that I need to create an NSAutoreleasePool at the start of the thread that this is happening on, but I'm not sure where in my code this is happening.  Is it possible to set a breakpoint that will be hit when the object in question is autoreleased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a symbolic breakpoint on __NSAutoreleaseNoPool and see which thread you're on when you hit it.  This can be done using the UI at the bottom of Xcode's Breakpoint Navigator, or on the GDB command line if you prefer, by entering the command: break __NSAutoreleaseNoPool

Answer (score 1):

From CocoaDev on [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging):

> This is an environment variable. When this environment variable is
>   set, with "setenv MallocStackLogging 1" in tcsh (for example), then
>   you can launch any app in that shell. Do not "open" the app, launch it
>   from the shell. When you do this all mallocs are tracked. Then saying,
>   in another shell, "leaks " or "leaks " will give you a
>   potentially voluminous list of the leaks in the app at that point.
>
> You can then loop over some series of actions and see if the number of
>   leaks changes between iterations. The leak has an id, which stays the
>   same for the lifetime of the app, the size and sometimes a guess as to
>   the type of the object being leaked, and a dump of the beginning bit
>   of the leaked data.
>
> Figuring how best to fix the leaks, and how to intepret some of the
>   things you see in the leaks dump is a separate thing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding an autorelease pool in your main function of your thread should fix your memory management problem. 
Like this

```
- (void)main
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ...
    Your code here
    ...

    [pool release];
}
```

or if you want to use the new syntax

```
- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        ... your code here ...
    }
}
```

Anyway, you should check all the NSDate created by a factory method or expressly autoreleased by you. All the factory method for the class NSDate are listed below

- date
- dateWithNaturalLanguageString:
- dateWithNaturalLanguageString:locale:
- dateWithString:
- dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:
- dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:
- dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:
- dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:

(from [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html))